# Highcharts export server execute javascript

Tags: highcharts

On the server side using the export server how can we have custom labels? For instance, on the client side in some cases we have custom js functions to create labels etc ... In this case 
formatDurationLabel is a custom function defined by us. How do I execute such functions on the export server?

```
this.chartOptions.yAxis.labels.formatter = this.formatDurationLabel;
```

Comment: Can someone from Highcharts please comment?

Comment: Can you please comment on this, this is very important for us, we are one of paid customers and have a support contract.

Comment: Do you have any answers?

Comment: Sorry, we have missed that. Do you have your own exporting server? If yes, you can create functions there. If not, what is wrong with this: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/754/ ? It exports properly with formatter.